# To add/remove Partition key and Row key to use Azure Tables with WebAPI

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am developing an application back-end using Azure and Web API. For this I have created some Azure tables. Below is the sample of my model.

```
public class Device : TableEntity
 {
   public Device(string partitionKey, string rowKey)
     {
        this.PartitionKey = partitionKey;
        this.RowKey = rowKey;
     }

      public Device() { }

      public string DeviceName { get; set; }

      public string DeviceOS { get; set; }

      public string Make { get; set; }
 }
```

The Partition Key is formed by using Table Name like UD_Device (UD_ being a constant and Device being the table name. The Row key is simply the DeviceName unique for all devices.

Now when I query these tables in my Web API I get a List of entities along with Partition key and Row key as properties in them.

This list I have to give it to the front-end angular application as JSON, but the Partition Key and Row Key are not to be sent while doing this.

Same thing when I am making a POST request i.e. when I am getting data from angular front-end and I have to send it to Azure Table, then the user does not send the Partition key and Row key. So how could I make a model which caters need to both this requirement?

Comment: Can you describe your model? Are the values stored in PartitionKey/RowKey are somehow reflected in the model (in some other properties)?

Comment: Yeah by getting the name of the model I can make the Partition Key and one of the property act as Row Key. I have 14 Azure tables and I am using the same concept in all of them.

Comment: For updating an entity, you would need to know the PartitionKey/RowKey. Since you mentioned that you can derive these values from your model, I suggest you do that instead of creating additional properties in your model for these two.

Comment: How do you determine to which table an object belongs to? Is there a list of objects per table?

Comment: How are your querying your tables now, using classed derived from `TableEntity` or  are you using `DynamicTableEntity` or another way?

Comment: @Gaurav but I am deriving my model from TableEntity. Partition Key and Row key are properties in the model but then I cannot expose this model to front-end. Also while sending back to Azure again I will have to get these keys for all the entities in my List.

Comment: @Peter I am querying using TableEntity. Yes for each table there is a corresponding model. Based on the Web API method called that particular table is queried meaning I have GET method for 3 tables because I know that only these three tables need to be used for GET. Therefore I can differentiate which Table I am querying. The problem is just that for back and forth how to handle these Partition Key and Row key without exposing them to inappropriate places like front-end.

Comment: Would you mind updating your question with some code?

Answer (score 0):

> This list I have to give it to the front-end angular application as JSON, but the Partition Key and Row Key are not to be sent while doing this.

In my sample, I could get all entity properties (include Partition Key and Row Key) by calling Web API from AngularJS client application. The following sample code is for your reference.

**Web API**

```
public class studentEntity : TableEntity
{
    public studentEntity(string lastName, string firstName)
    {
        this.PartitionKey = lastName;
        this.RowKey = firstName;
    }

    public studentEntity() { }

    public int Age { get; set; }

}

public List<studentEntity> Get()
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();


    CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("student");

    TableQuery<studentEntity> rangeQuery = new TableQuery<studentEntity>().Where(
        TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "Harp"));

    List<studentEntity> list = table.ExecuteQuery(rangeQuery).ToList();
    return list;
}
```

**AngularJS**

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://XXX/api/values")
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.mydata = response.data;
    });
});
```

[image]

If my sample code could not help you find the issue with your sample, you could share us your code of Web API (retrieving entities and return entity list) and AngularJS (sending request to Web API ). And then we will reproduce the issue based on your code.

Comment: I understand that you are using First Name and Last Name as your Partition Key and Row Key, but as I gave my model code above I make the partition key using my model name so it is not a property in my model and so I don't want the user to see it or I don't want to send it to the angular part like you are doing

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is a Data Transfer Object.

1. You make a class that represents the model you want to expose to your clients
2. Before you send to the client, transform your data object to this new DTO class
3. When a client sends you one of these DTOs, transform it to your data object and send it to Storage, or get the existing from Storage and patch it with the new data

A library such as AutoMapper can make this process much easier.

Comment: Can this be done using one model for one table itself, as I have 14 tables.

Comment: With this approach, you will have to make a DTO for every single table type. If someone comes up with a better approach that involves less repetition then you should go with that :)

Comment: ok.. thanks, but I need an approach where I can do it by just one model

Comment: If you're only wanting to use one model but you have 14 tables I would say that you probably aren't going about this correctly... But any case you can just create a class full of type `object` and just create some sort of method that maps your properties from the Azure tables to this end-all-be-all class.

Comment: No I don't have one model. I have 14 different models. But I don't want to use another 14 models to communicate between my Web API and front-end.